# Regex rewrite rule

Tags: regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have following rewrite rule implemented in the website

```
add_rewrite_tag('%c%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^blog/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?', 'index.php?pagename=blog&c=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

It works when I have the exact match, for example

```
https://example.com/blog/category
```

But when URL contains any query parameter it does not match

```
https://example.com/blog/category?utm_campaign=web
```

I want to match and retain any query parameter from the URL if exist, how do I go about it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please do confirm if you are hitting `https://example.com/blog/category?utm_campaign=web` in browser?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I confirm I tested with the URL you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to define the query parameter key by using `add_rewrite_tag(...)`; probably because of this, we cannot declare an unknown number of query parameters. If someone has another solution, I would be happy to learn it. The following code is for only the "utm_campaign" parameter.

```php
add_rewrite_tag('%c%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_tag('%utm_campaign%', '([^&]+)');

add_rewrite_rule('^blog/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?(?:[?].*utm_campaign=([^&\s]+))?', 'index.php?pagename=blog&c=$matches[1]&utm_campaign=$matches[2]', 'top');
```

Comment: Not sure why, but this is not working...

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar Since I don't have the rest of the codes, I can't test them. I updated the answer. Can you try the new updated one?

Comment: still not working :-(, utm_campaign param was just an example, it may contain any URL param, I just want rewrite_rule to ignore any param